# Wrong in a small function [ Php 7_0_0]

Tags: php

```
function getDisplayName($username) {
    $query = "SELECT `dispname` FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`='slavidodo'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row["dispname"];
}
```

I tested the codes without using a function and worked fine ( idk why don't work when using function).

Regars Ahmed.

Comment: I found the solution. to global $conn.

Comment: global is generally a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

Because your connection `$conn` is not available in your function scope. Either use `global` or pass the connection `$conn` to your function parameter.

**Method(1):**

```
function getDisplayName($username) {
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT `dispname` FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`='slavidodo'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row["dispname"];
}
```

**Method(2):**

```
function getDisplayName($username, $conn) {
    $query = "SELECT `dispname` FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`='slavidodo'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row["dispname"];
}
```

Comment: @NanaPartykar Dhanyawad. :)